# Can i read private messages with the Facebook API?

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to develop a web app that would read your entire messages history on facebook/messenger and give you insight about the conversations.

My question is: Is it possible ? Can i read the messages that are not destined to me via the API ?
I searched through the documentation but didn't find anything

Answer (score 1):

I disagree, it looks like Graph version 3.0 has the API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.0/user/inbox

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: Link broken as of october 2020

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/user/inbox

> This document refers to a feature that was removed after Graph API v2.4.

In other words, there is no way to access the user messages (anymore).